# android - Fragment onCreateView not called after update and commiting transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am unable to get a fragment to update after changing data. I call

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();

but onCreateView does not get called. I tried several different ways in refreshFragment(). I do see messages for "I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu" after I put in the above line of code so something is happening, but onCreateView() is not getting called.

`public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainActivityFragment.class);
String poolWord = "ABCDE";
String newWord = "";

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    logger.info("onCreate------------------------");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

 }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    logger.info("onCreateView------------------------");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    GridView gridViewPool = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewPool);
    gridViewPool.setAdapter(new LetterImageAdapter(getActivity(), poolWord));
    gridViewPool.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            logger.error("po    " + position);
            updateWords(position);
            refreshFragment();
        }
    });
    GridView gridviewNewWord = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewNewWord);
    gridviewNewWord.setAdapter(new LetterImageAdapter(getActivity(), ""));
    return view;
}

private void refreshFragment() {
    logger.info("refreshFragment------------------------");
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, this).attach(this).commit();
    // Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commit();

    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}`

Comment: I modified refreshFragment() and broke it up to individual lines, then added some logging to see if the fragment is detached. isDetached returns false both before and after I call transaction.detach(). I'm new to this so not sure what might be going on

Answer (score 0):

After several hours, I got it to work. Not sure of all the details as this is my first android project. Posting an answer in case anybody else has the same problem.

The crux of the problem, I suspect, is the generated code from Intellij did not start a transaction in the Activity class. It did not include

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

I'm not sure how my MainActivityFragment was created without this, but it was.I also replaced the generated activity-main.xml with one I had from a tutorial. The one from Intellij did not have an android:id that I could use for the container object. It also contained other stuff I did not need at this time.The new activity-main.xml looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

The old generated one was:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There was also a content-main.xml which I got rid of. That may be what android used to generate my MainActivityFragment without explicit code. Someone more experienced with android development may be able to answer that.

```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/fragment"
      android:name="com.ultramondo.mywordandroid.MainActivityFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

  </fragment>
```

I'm sure there's some useful stuff I can go back to but for now I want simplicity. I also had to make some changes to use android.support.v4.app packages for Fragment and Transaction classes. It's kind of like coming in the middle of a movie and figuring out what the plot is. Once I see the whole movie, I'm sure it will become clearer.